# certificate_unknown exception in ssl

Tags: java, ssl

I have a server and client, they both communicate between each other using ssl. The previous self signed sslkeystore expired at the server, so I generated a new one with the same details with the extended validity . But now when I try to communicate to the server from the client, I get the following exception.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1991)
```

It was working till I updated the keystore.

Its creating the exception from the following block of  code. When I try to read from the  `BufferedInputStream bis`.

```
    private byte[] readBytesFromStream(BufferedInputStream bis) throws IOException {

    byte[] lengthBytes = new byte[4];
    bis.read(lengthBytes);
    int length = ByteBuffer.wrap(lengthBytes).getInt();
    System.out.print("length : " + length);

    byte[] data = new byte[length];
    bis.read(data);

    return data;
}
```

Should I do something else to reflect the updated keystore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to make the public key of the server trusted by the keystore in the client. Then onwards it started working. Also I found an excellent tool online which will help to deal with this kind of things with keystores and certificates its called  portecle (https://sourceforge.net/projects/portecle/)